# How to access mysql prompt from Homebrew installed mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have installed mysql using Homebrew.  So far I've only access Homebrew's version of mysql from Ruby on Rails applications, so I haven't had to access its mysql prompt.  But now I want to access the mysql prompt from the version of mysql that Homebrew has installed.  Right now when I type in "mysql" in my terminal, I access a version located at /usr/local/bin/mysql.  This is different from where Homebrew has mysql installed.

How can I access Homebrew's mysql prompt?  Is there a simple way to get rid of the version at /usr/local/bin/mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew installs symlinks from `/usr/local/bin/` to the real location. So if you're loading the `mysql` CLI from `/usr/local/bin/` you're running the Homebrew version.

You can check, if you like, but doing `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mysql`. It should show a symlink to something like `../Cellar/mysql/(some version)/bin/mysql`

Comment: You are correct, there is a symlink from /usr/local/bin/mysql to ../Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin/mysql.  But, what is interesting is that none of my databases are listed when I do a "describe databases" from the mysql command prompt.  So it has to be accessing a different mysql instance.

Comment: Or!  Maybe my Rails projects are accessing a different version of mysql.  Where could this possibly be?

Comment: In that case, I'd be looking at what credentials you gave Rails to connect with and using those. Assuming you have actually told Rails ro use MySQL.

Comment: I figured it out!  I wasn't logging into the mysql as root user, which means I wasn't able to see all the available tables.  Logging in as root lets me see all the tables.  There's only one mysql running!  Woo!